# Navigation Experimental - Replace NavigationHeader Title Within a Scenes View

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I'm trying to update the NavigationHeader title (along with left and right components) from a specific scene's view.

Example:

1. User navigates to profile view
2. Get data from server
3. Call redux action to update the navigation header with the username

My current approach is not working too well. I'm trying to use the NavigationStateUtils to replace the scene with an updated version of itself. This works if my view is the first one in the stack. However, if I try adding the call to update nav header on a route that isn't the first, it will freeze because the navigation hasn't finished it's animation.

I could try adding a timeout on the call, but it seems hacky to come up with a delay that makes sense globally.

```
case UPDATE_NAV_HEADER: {
  const tabs = state.get('tabs')
  const tabKey = tabs.getIn(['routes', tabs.get('index')]).get('key')
  const scenes = state.get(tabKey).toJS()
  const route = scenes.routes.slice(-1)[0]

  var leftComponent = null
  if (action.payload.leftComponent) {
    leftComponent = action.payload.leftComponent
  } else if (route.navLeftComponent) {
    leftComponent = route.navLeftComponent
  }

  var rightComponent = null
  if (action.payload.rightComponent) {
    rightComponent = action.payload.rightComponent
  } else if (route.navRightComponent) {
    rightComponent = route.navRightComponent
  }

  const newScene = NavigationStateUtils.replaceAt(
    scenes,
    route.key,
    {
      key: route.key,
      title: action.payload.newTitle ? action.payload.newTitle : route.title,
      navLeftComponent: leftComponent,
      navRightComponent: rightComponent,
      shouldRenderHeader: "shouldRenderHeader" in route ? route.shouldRenderHeader : true,
      shouldRenderTabBar: "shouldRenderTabBar" in route ? route.shouldRenderTabBar : true
    }
  )

  return state.set(tabKey, fromJS(newScene))
}
```